# How to highlight dynamic code in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, dynamic-language-runtime, dynamic-code

Is it possible and if so how, to make Visual Studio highlight dynamic expressions in code?

When I just hovered above some code, visual studio told me it was a dynamic expression. This made me realize I made a mistake in my code and used one dynamic too many. But I also realized that if I had not hovered, a 'huge swath' of dynamic code that was supposed to be static would have escaped.

So I wondered if it is possible to make Visual Studio change the background color of dynamic expressions, so those pieces will be clearly recognizable.

[edit]
With dynamic expressions I mean the use of the dynamic keyword in regular code.

Comment: +1 Great question... it's what scares me away from the DLR.

Comment: Sorry, I'm clueless - what do you mean dynamic code here? Operations on a `dynamic` variable? The System.CodeDom classes? Something else?

Comment: @Rup, with dynamic code I mean the use of the dynamic keyword. Edited the question a bit to clarify. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Have you visited the Visual Studio Gallery to check the avaliable extensions?

Comment: @Morvader, I didn't even know such site existed. I'll check it out.

Comment: Have you tried Visual Assist by wholetomato.com? Not sure if it provides the feature you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need an Extension. You can create your own, but I would suggest getting pre-built ones.

Visual Studio has a lot of extensions lately, because of it's popularity.
There are many options I could suggest, but many are rather buggy, so I would suggest using one of the safer, more well known ones like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html) (my all time favorite and that of many others as well)

I also like [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx).

There are so many others available though, and if you want to find them, cruise down the Visual Studio Gallery like Morvader said.
[Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/)

EDIT:
2 notes I forgot to mention:

- Dynamic Intellisense is included in Resharper
- Dynamic Highlighting is included as well. If you want to modify the color from the default light blue you can go to `Tools->Options...->Environments->Fonts and Colors->Display items->`ReSharper Late Bound Identifier
  Also make sure that in `Resharper->Options...->Code Inspection->Settings` "Enable code analysis" and "Color identifiers" are checked.

Comment: Thanks - can you recommend a pre-built extension that will highlight `dynamic` variables? (or can be configured to?)

Comment: @Rup Resharper has it prebuilt. Edited the answer to clarify that.
@Patrick Huizinga , tell me if this solves your problem buddy.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I found the color option you mentioned. At first ran into the issue that I did not have Resharper coloring enabled. I edited your answer about the specific option and about enabling coloring. (now if only someone could approve it)